# Date not equal to today

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-18-01 |
| 1 | 2021-17-01 |

How can I keep rows if the date column has a value not equal to today's date (17th Jan)?

```
df[df.date != datetime.datetime.today().date()]
```

Expected Output

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-18-01 |

Comment: Use `pd.DataFrame.loc` method

Comment: That still shows me rows equal to today's date

Comment: use `pd.Datetime` or `pd.Timestamp` object `df[df['date'].ne(pd.Timestamp('today')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format="%Y-%d-%m")
df[df.date!=str(datetime.datetime.today().date())]
```

---

```
    date
1   2021-01-17
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup:

Here we populate a dataframe and convert the data to correct datatypes

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(id=0, date='2021-01-17'), 
                     dict(id=1, date='2021-01-18'), 
                     dict(id=2, date='2021-01-19')])
df = df.set_index('id')
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

The result would look like this:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-17 |
| 1 | 2021-01-18 |
| 2 | 2021-01-19 |

#### Filtering:

```
df.loc[df.date.dt.date != pd.Timestamp.now().date()]
```

The result would look like this (In my timezone it is January, 18th already):

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-17 |
| 2 | 2021-01-19 |

#### Explanation

We use LocIndexer .loc accessor to filter the dataframe via an array of booleans.

In order to make the comparison correct we take the `date()` part from the current timestamp on the right hand side and use the DateTimeProperties `.dt` accessor to use `date` property of the underlying Datetime object for the left hand side.